# Converting VB to C# and getting a method name expected error

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting some code from VB into C#, but in doing so I am getting a 'method name expected' error for **jo** in - interviewID = int.Parse(**jo**("interviewID"));.  The error comes back as - 'jo' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'.

Here is the original VB code:

```
Private interviewID As Integer
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
    Dim line As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(line)
    interviewID = CInt(jo("interviewID"))


    GetIntervieweeTableInfo();
    WriteCallback(context, interviewee);
End Sub
```

Here it is converted to C#:

```
 private int interviewID;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(line);
        interviewID = int.Parse(jo("interviewID"));


        GetIntervieweeTableInfo();
        WriteCallback(context, interviewee);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably `jo["interviewID"]`  c# uses square brackets for indexing

Answer (score 5):

`jo("interviewID")` in VB calls an [**indexer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) in the `JObject` class, which in C# is done using square brackets `[]` instead of the normal parenthesis `()`.

The correct code should be:

```
interviewID = int.Parse(jo["interviewID"]);
```

Comment: Just giving you a hard time - your bias is showing

Comment: @Plutonix : Heh, you're confusing me. Bias to whom or what? VB.NET? I actually like C# too, I just use VB.NET more often ;). Both are very powerful languages.

Comment: @VisualVincent, maybe when you said "normal parenthesis" as opposed to the abnormal C# square brackets. :-)

Comment: @Mary : True. Though I never meant to say that C# is abnormal in any way. Even if I didn't program I would still call it "normal parenthesis" because they're used most often in written text as well. ;)